# Export pasword ldap (openldap) on liferay not working

Tags: passwords, ldap, liferay, openldap

I have configured liferay to authenticated to OpenLdap. Cas, import and export is activated.

User create from OpenLdap can authenticate to portal, also is imported into Liferay. It seems importing process is ok.

When user try to modify an attribute other than password the data is modified on OpenLdap.

The problem is when user try to modify their password. Liferay ask for current pass and the new one. It get a error saying credentials an incorrect.

If i try to modify the password of the user with a administrator user, Liferay only ask for the new password. After that, the user with de password changed by de admin user can log in with the new password. So, it seems password is modified correctly on OpenLdap. If user, try to modify again the password, Liferay say that everything was ok, but the user cannot autenticate with the new passord, only with old password.

After that if I try to change de password again with admin user, Liferay say that everthing was ok but the user now cannot authenticate with new password.

I'm using Liferay 6.2 ce.

I have modified :

```
ldap.auth.method=password-compare
ldap.auth.password.encryption.algorithm=SHA
ldap.auth.method=bind
```

on portal-setup-wizard.properties`enter code here`

Any Idea?
Thanks very much in advance.

with several values without success.

Answer (score 0):

[Compare](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Authentication#section-LDAP+Authentication-CompareRequestForPasswords) is **not** a best practice for LDAP in general.

"[Bind is preferred](https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/LDAP#section-LDAP-Settings+Explained) by most vendors so that you don't have to worry about  encryption strategies."

Also there appears to be a [bug in LifeRay](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-57602) that may affect your version.

Comment: I also tried "bind" with same result. I read the bug but I think is not the same problem because in my case when user is created from openldap it can authenticate.